# Where does Javascript get timezone information from?

Tags: javascript

So I know there are many discussions related to how to get a timezone in javascript and many methods of doing so such as using the Date.getTimezoneOffset() method or using a library such as moment.js.  But where does this timezone information come from on the client's machine?  Is it a browser setting? An OS setting?

Comment: It comes from the OS.

Comment: The browser uses the OS setting, yes. It would be possible, but quite unlikely, that there is a separate setting.

Comment: [Mozilla Docs say "host system"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does JavaScript get a new Date() from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581421/where-does-javascript-get-a-new-date-from)